# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 in subcomponent (png)

Tags: ios, xcode

The codesigning process fails when it tries to sign my app. As the affected subcomponent is the app's png icon mentioned.

```
/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aeqboqclqpxecfgjtkrlgvqkhzxb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aeqboqclqpxecfgjtkrlgvqkhzxb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I'm quite irritated as I'm seeing this for the first time.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that `.png` "OK" (can you view it)?  This error normally only affects other signable components (i.e. `.framework` and `.dylib` files) and not `.png` files.  I therefore wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't a `.png` file at all.

Comment: When Xcode starts to loose it, the first thing to do is quit it and remove the `DerivedData` folder : `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. If that doesn't work you indeed have a problem.

Comment: @Droppy The image is a valid png file.

Comment: @deadbeef Did that already with no effect.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: XCode 8. I just recreated the project, copied all stuff over, bang - runs. thx@all

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this issue. you should navigate to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData here and remove MyApp-aeqboqclqpxecfgjtkrlgvqkhzxb using this rm -rf command. then restart your xcode.

Comment: I solved it already myself. See my comment from August 23 (last comment on my question).

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem (codesign failed with exit code 1 in .png subcomponent) week ago, spent so long to find the right answer. Leaving my solution here and hoping someone.

Background: I was merging some framework from another apps, and don't know why that Xcode copy an extra "Resource" file under the Framework group (the "Resource" file having the same path as the "Resource" group which is on the same level to Framework group).

All I do is to right-click and "remove reference" of the duplicated "Resource" file, and build successfully.

I guess Xcode is just not happy about the duplicated "Resource" group/file (showing in the Project Navigator), and I would suggest anyone having a codesign failed in subcomponent of .png file to **check if their "Resource" group is duplicated.**